# Unix Time For China

Tags: java, simpledateformat, unix-timestamp, worldtimeapi

I am trying to get the local time of China. I get the unixTimeStamp from the worldtimeapi.org website.

Problem: I get my local time instead of China time.

```
private class BackgroundProcess extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {




    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String value = null;
        HttpHandler httpHandler = new HttpHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String url = "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Shanghai";

        String jsonStr = httpHandler.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

               value = jsonObj.getString("unixtime");

                Log.e(TAG, "Operation Okay: " + "\n\n"+value);

            } catch (final JSONException e) {

                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());



            }

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");

        }

        return value ;





    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        Toast.makeText(Timer_FullTime.this, aVoid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        long l = Long.valueOf(aVoid);
        long milliSec = l * 1000 ;



        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a dd/MM/yyyy");
        String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(milliSec));
        currentTime.setText("" + dateString);
    }
}
```

I do not understand why I cannot get time of China that is 6:30 something now,
instead I keep getting my local time that is 3:54 something right now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you're not setting the timezone of the SimpleDateFormat to anything other than your default timezone so it displays he unix time (which is identical everywhere in the world) in your timezone. All you need to get the current timestamp is `System.currentTimeMillis()`. To get the current time in Shanghai, all you need is `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Shanghai"))`

Comment: first thank you for your time secondly by using LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Shanghai")) do i need to call the api for the millsecond from worldtimeapi.prg

Comment: No. Calling a REST service to know what time it is is useless. Your computer already knows what time it is. And the JVM has timezone data allowing to format the currrent time to any timezone, as I showed.

Comment: You can use LocalDateTime if your minSdkVersion is 26 (Android 8.0) but problem is my minsdkversion is 19

Comment: @saadzahoor I would suggest trying JodaTime in this case

Comment: @RoderickLenz I would suggest using the *Threeten-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects rather than Joda-Time for older Android.

Comment: Never use `LocalDateTime` to track a moment. Read the class JavaDoc. I cannot imagine a case where calling `LocalDateTime.now` is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Never use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## *java.time*

You appear to be getting a long integer number representing the number of whole seconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 UTC.

If so, parse as an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSeconds( seconds ) ;
```

Adjust from UTC to your particular time zone by applying a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Shanghai" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

For older Android, see the Threeten-Backport and ThreeTenABP projects.

All this has been covered many many times already. Search Stack Overflow before posting.